# Exception.getStackTraceString() returning '()' on object with managed package trigger when debug logs not on

Tags: exception, debug-logs, stacktrace

First of all, my question is very similar to [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253445/exception-method-getstacktracestring-is-empty) and might actually be a duplicate, however there is no notion of a managed package or debug logs there.

We have an after insert trigger on Account doing something like:

```
    try{
        //some code that will cause a DMLException
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Exception_Log__c el = new Exception_Log__c();
        el.Stack_Trace_String__c = e.getStackTraceString();
        el.Message__c = e.getMessage();
        el.Line_Number__c = e.getLineNumber();
        el.Type_Name__c = e.getTypeName();
        insert el;             
    }
```

Additionally, we have an installed **managed package that has an Account trigger** that will also fire.

We get this result when the code executes:

[image]

When I **turn on debug logs** for my user

[image]

and execute the code again, I get this result:

[image]

So it seems the stack trace is being wiped out if somewhere in the execution we have passed through managed code, and only if we are not generating debug logs? We understand the stack trace has no info when the exception is generated from the managed package for IP reasons, but why are we not able to see the stack trace when it is generated from our own code and how can we work around this?

Comment: does [this KA](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319981&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) help? Quote: **When the managed package debug Logs are enabled, you can see the complete stack trace in results**

Comment: did you ever figure this out @Robin ?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana Unfortunately not.